# How do I define a regex to match values in a csv file that include the separator?

Tags: r, regex, awk, sed

I was trying to check some government data from Brazil and the `CSV` file was giving me some trouble using read.csv and fread (from data.table R package).
fread pointed me to some of the rows in error and I found out that one of the fields had ';' in there.

One example of bad row is below. Note the third field has a ';'.

```
29561;5001;"Urbanização - Eixo Borda da Baía - Urbanização Mirante do Bonfim e Pedra furada; Bananeiras, Miramar e Alagados IV e V - Salvador - BA";;;48030000.00;BA;SALVADOR;Estado;Ministério das Cidades;71;31/10/2014;11/11/2010;;"12 53'26.843964""S";"38 26'16.689156""O";;
```

I tried to define a regexp to replace the ';' by ',' or something else and I didn't get it.
I ended up using `awk` to find all rows with a different number of fields in the records and luckily enough it was just 5 rows in the 56k+ rows file.

What regexp could I use to replace the ';' in those fields?
I tried the regexp below in grep (gnu grep version 2.6.3)
(a number followed by a semicolon followed by double quotes followed by anything followed by semicolon followed by anything followed by double quotes).
[0-9]+;\".*?;.*?\"

Comment: `read.table('tmp.csv', sep = ';')` works perfectly for me

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Regex is a good solution for this. Try the "read.table" method in R. It allows you to specify separator, quotes, headers and several other options. It may take a few tries to get everything perfect, but it should work. Try something like this:

`data=read.table(file="filename.txt",sep=";",quote="\"",na.strings="",header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)`

Check out `help(read.table)` for the full details.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the best solution is to try and replace the semicolons within the fields. It's quite common to find the field separator within a field - that's what the double quotes around the content are for.

Any half-decent CSV parser can handle this format. For example, using the `csv` core module in python:

```
import csv
with open('file') as file:
  reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
  for row in reader:
    print '\n'.join(row)
```

This gives the output:

```
29561
5001
Urbanização - Eixo Borda da Baía - Urbanização Mirante do Bonfim e Pedra furada; Bananeiras, Miramar e Alagados IV e V - Salvador - BA


48030000.00
BA
SALVADOR
Estado
Ministério das Cidades
71
31/10/2014
11/11/2010

12 53'26.843964"S
38 26'16.689156"O
```

As you can see, the field containing the semicolon has still been parsed correctly as a single field.

To be honest I'm surprised that the R module doesn't work. Perhaps there's some way of defining the quote character?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for FPAT (see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Splitting-By-Content):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS=";"; FPAT="([^"OFS"]*)|(\"[^\"]*\")" }
{
    for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
        gsub(OFS,",",$i)
    }
    print
}
$ gawk -f tst.awk file     
29561;5001;"Urbanização - Eixo Borda da Baía - Urbanização Mirante do Bonfim e Pedra furada, Bananeiras, Miramar e Alagados IV e V - Salvador - BA";;;48030000.00;BA;SALVADOR;Estado;Ministério das Cidades;71;31/10/2014;11/11/2010;;"12 53'26.843964""S";"38 26'16.689156""O";;
```